# Binding datatables ajax request to different button

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a datatable that is configured as

```
var table = $(".datatable").DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: {
    url: $("#datatable").attr("data-search"),
    dataType: "JSON",
    complete: function (data) {
      $(".total-records").html(data.responseJSON.recordsTotal);
      $("#maxPageText").html(`of ${table.page.info().pages} <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" style="font-weight:200;"></i>`);

    }
  },
});
table.ajax.reload();
```

Everything works fine, search, sort and all. But, I'm trying to make a different textbox as search which is present in modal. I am trying to send ajax request and rebuild the datatable with new data return from that particular ajax but it doesn't seem to rebuild with new data.

This is the code

```
$("body").on("click", ".advance-search", function () {

  var type = $(this).attr("data-type");
  var value = "";
  var search = $(this).attr("data-search");

  if (type == "tag") {
    value = $("#tagSearchInput").val();
  } else {
    value = $(".input-advance-search").val();
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: search,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: { "type": type, "value": value, "data": table.data().ajax.params() },
    complete: function (data) {
      console.log(data.responseJSON);
      table.clear().rows.add(data.responseJSON.data).draw();
      return false;
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Notice that I have added `return false` in two places because right after this ajax request another ajax request is sent which seems to be from this line `table.clear().rows.add(data.responseJSON.data).draw();` via stacktrace.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you make [ajax option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) as a function. And inside that function check for the value of `#tagSearchInput` or `.input-advance-search` and append it along with the `data`. Then make an ajax call using [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) api and pass the new customized data.

```
var table = $(".datatable").DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  // use ajax as a function
  ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {

    // get the 'data-type' and 'data-search' attribute
    var type = $(".advance-search").attr("data-type"),
    search = $(".advance-search").attr("data-search"),
    value = "";

    if (type == "tag") {
      value = $("#tagSearchInput").val();
    } else {
      value = $(".input-advance-search").val();
    }

    // append the 'type' and 'value' in 'data'
    data.type = type;
    data.value = value;

    // make ajax call using jquery ajax api
    $.ajax({
      url: search,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "JSON",

      // pass new customized data
      data: data,
      complete: function (data) {
        $(".total-records").html(data.responseJSON.recordsTotal);
        $("#maxPageText").html(`of ${table.page.info().pages} <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" style="font-weight:200;"></i>`);

        // call the callback function with the result
        callback(data.responseJSON.data);
      }
    });
  },
});
```

Now on the click event of `.advance-search` you have to just reload the table using [`draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) api.

```
$("body").on("click", ".advance-search", function () {
  table.draw();
});
```

With this approach, your code will look cleaner and elegant.

---

Now in context to your worry about the ajax request is being sent after another ajax request because of the following code

```
table.clear().rows.add(data.responseJSON.data).draw();
```

That ajax call is happening because of the [`draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) method. It is because when server-side processing enabled, a [`draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) will always trigger a reload. Also `clear()` won't empty the table since it is a client-side function. For more info check [processing modes part of the manual](https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Processing-modes).